# How to get back to python virtual environment in mac command line

Tags: python, command-line, pyvenv

I am having a bit of difficulty reinitiating my virtual environment on my preprod server on command line. I think when I quit out of my preprod server the other day, I also quit out of my virtual environment, because now it doesn't say (env) in front of the preprod prompt:

```
Before: (env) SAS@preprod:~$
Now: SAS@preprod:~$
```

I am logged into my preprod server now, and I have a virtual_environment_command.txt file, and a config file accessible. I just don't know how to activate either of those documents so I can utilize my virtual environment for testing the code for an api document I'm working on. Thanks!

Comment: `cd` into whatever folder you made it in and just do `source bin/activate`

Answer (score 3):

You have to find the directory where the virtualenv was created. e.g. when you created it using `virtualenv env` it would create a directory called `env` and you can activate it using:

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your responses! They were very helpful! I also ended up clicking the up arrow enough times to figure out what I typed in before to reactivate the venv a few days ago (yes it was a lot of clicking, lol) and found that the following command also proved to fix the problem:

```
SAS@preprod:~$$(cat virtual_environment_command.txt )
```

And that extra $ is not a typo, it goes the prompt and then $(cat virtual_environment_command.txt)

Thank you again!

Comment: And I forgot to add that I created the virtual environment in the general directory, so I didn't have to cd into another folder to access the virtual environment. Had I made the virtual environment in another folder, then I would have absolutely had to have moved into the other folder first. Thanks again!